# Objective-C: Logic Question

Tags: objective-c

Hey guys, I'm getting a little trouble here. I have a view that makes a grid display. I mean, I have 9 items and sets to display 3 per line. Resulting in 3 lines. That's OK. What I don't understang, it's why always I get a space between them. Sometimes it comes up and on the middle of the lines. The space is equal to one line height.

Check the code:

```
NSInteger quantidadeDeVideos = [self.videosURL count];
NSInteger contadorDeVideos = 0;

NSInteger idLinha = 0;
NSInteger linha = 1;
NSInteger itemq = 0;

while (contadorDeVideos < quantidadeDeVideos) {

    float f;
    float g;

    // Set the lines

    if (itemq < 3) {
        itemq++;
    }
    else {
        itemq = 1;
        linha++;
    }

    // This makes the second line multiplies for 150;
    if (linha > 1) {
        g = 150;
    }
    else {
        g = 0;
    }


    // Ignore this, this is foi make 1,2,3. Making space between the itens.

    if (idLinha > 2) {
        idLinha = 0;
    }


    NSLog(@"%i", foi);

    float e = idLinha*250+15;
    f = linha*g;

    UIImageView *thumbItem = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    thumbItem.frame = CGRectMake(e, f, 231, 140);

    UIColor *bkgColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"VideosItemBackground.png"]];
    thumbItem.backgroundColor = bkgColor;
    thumbItem.opaque = NO;

    [self.videosScroll addSubview:thumbItem];

    contadorDeVideos++;
    idLinha++;

}
```

This is the result should be:

[][][]
[][][]
[][][]

And this is what I'm getting:

[][][]
[][][]
[][][]

Thanks for all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `linha` is 1, `g` is 0, making `linha * g` 0. For the subsequent lines, `g` is 150, making `linha * g` == 300 for the second iteration (a jump of 300 over the first), after which it increases by 150 each time. Instead of conditionally setting `g` each time through, you should just make it a constant 150 and then either use `(linha - 1) * g` for the value of `f` or just start `linha` at 0.

If you want to see how to spot the problem yourself:

1. Ask yourself, what is going wrong here?

   - The rectangles are being drawn one row too low
   - It only happens *after* the first row
2. So we look at the line that's responsible for where the rectangles are drawn:

   ```
   thumbItem.frame = CGRectMake(e, f, 231, 140)
   ```
3. The variable `f` is the y-coordinate. This has to be what's messed up. Let's see how `f` is defined:

   ```
   f = linha*g;
   ```
4. OK, `linha` is the line number and it's only changed once in the loop without any conditional logic. So the problem is probably `g`. Let's see how that one is defined:

   ```
   if (linha > 1) {
       g = 150;
   }
   else {
       g = 0;
   }
   ```
5. Hey, `g` changes after the first iteration — precisely when our problem crops up. Let's see what the values of `linha*g` are:

   ```
   1 * 0 = 0
   2 * 150 = 300 (+300)
   3 * 150 = 450 (+150)
   4 * 150 = 600 (+150)
   ```

Ah-ha — the problem is that setting `g` to 0 on the first iteration breaks the pattern.